# Legal redress against smaller HMRC decisions?

Tags: united-kingdom, tax-law, court

I understand most of the "regular" decisions like tax assessment, etc. from HMRC (*Her Majesty's Revenue and Customs* - the UK's principal tax authority) are appealable, ie. you can refer them to the tax tribunal.

I was incorrectly charged late interest, which apparently is not charged through a formal decision, but "statutorily". Because of that, the tax tribunal doesn't have jurisdiction over that.

Is there a different mechanism for legal redress in cases where the dispute with HMRC is not over an appealable decision?

Answer (score 1):

I assume this relates to Self Assessment. If so you [appeal direct to HMRC](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/self-assessment-appeal-against-penalties-for-late-filing-and-late-payment-sa370) by using...

> ... the online service to appeal a £100 late filing penalty, or form SA370 to appeal any late filing or late payment penalty.
>
> [...]
>
> You must appeal within 30 days of the date HMRC sent you the penalty notice and have a reasonable excuse for late filing. Read the guidance on appealing against penalties for late filing and late payment before starting your appeal.
>
> You can either:
>
> use the online service to appeal against a £100 late filing penalty for tax returns from 6 April 2015 onwards
>
> print the postal form SA370, fill it in and post to HMRC to appeal against a penalty for:
>
> - sending tax returns late for earlier years
> - paying your tax late
> - sending a 2015 to 2016 tax return late, if you don’t want to use the online form service

Then...

If HMRC does not agree your appeal the SA370 Notes (a pdf found in the above link) say:

> - we’ll write to you to say why and tell you what you need to do if you
>   do not agree with our decision
> - you must pay the penalty and any added interest

What "you need to do" will be fact-specific to each individual case.

Comment: an appeal can only be filed against an appealable decision. The question is about disputes not involving appealable decisions. Note that "late filling" and "late payment penalty" you cite is different from "late interest" mentioned in the question.

Comment: For added context, in my case I filed an appeal (and forwarded it to a tax tribunal) and both the tribunal and hmrc answered "we don't respond as it's not an appealable decision".

Comment: @sygi Ah, ok. Looks like I'll need some more info to amend my answer. So how did the late interest payment come about? e.g. Did you file on time and they made a boob, or were you late etc..?

Comment: In detail, I amended the return and paid right after they processed the amendment, the dispute is over whether the deadline to pay should count from the original date, or the time amendment is processed (how I understand par. 2 (1) Schedule 3ZA of TMA).

The question is more general than this particular case, though: there are many situations where one may want to resolve a dispute with hmrc over something that's not an appealable decision.